# How to retrieve nested JSON values

Tags: json

I have the fallowing JSON object and I want to take the value of `Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork`

```
  [
      {
        "id": 13,
        "rev": 12,
        "fields": {
          "System.Id": 13,
          "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork": 32,
          "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork": 20
        },
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/.../_apis/wit/workItems/13"
      }
    ]
```

I am able retrieve data until some point:

```
console.log("object of json : ",result);
console.log("result[0] : ", result[0])
console.log("result[0].fields : ", result[0].fields)
```

The console output is,

[image]

But I this is not working   `result[0].fields.Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access data like an associative array :

```
result[0].fields['Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
result[0].fields["Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork"]
```

Basically when you use

```
result[0].fields.Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork
```

each time you use a ".", you are trying to get the value from a nested object, like this -

```
[
      {
        "id": 13,
        "rev": 12,
        "fields": {
          "System.Id": 13,
          "Microsoft": {
              "VSTS": {
                  "Scheduling": {
                      "RemainingWork": 32
                   }
               }
          },
          "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork": 20
        },
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/.../_apis/wit/workItems/13"
      }
    ]
```

which is not correct since that is not the way your data is structured.